# Single selection using tkinter.tix.CheckList class

Tags: python, tkinter, tix-checklist

Can we make single selection using [`tix.checklist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html#tkinter.tix.CheckList)? Like you can select only one customer (if you click on john it will mark john but then if you click stephen, john will be unselected that time ans stephen will be selected.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The `tkinter.tix` (Tk Interface Extension) module has been deprecated since version 3.6. It's unmaintained and should not be used in new code as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html#module-tkinter.tix). Moreover, you are unlikely to get help unless you add some a [mre] to you question.

Comment: You could simply use a `ttk.Treeview` with `selectmode="browse"` and use images if you want a tickbox  in addition to the selection highlight.